# Getting wrong sum of random number

Tags: c, random

I am on dice game in which i need to roll the dice 5 times and sum the random number. Everything is working fine but my sum is not according to the random number which i am getting

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    printf(" %d time dice rolled = %d \n",i, rand() % s + 1);
    x += rand() % s + 1;

}
printf("--------------------------------------Sum is %d", x);

getch();

}
```

s is the sides of the dice

Comment: do you know that every time you call `rand()` you're getting different value, right? so you're printing one value, but adding another one

Comment: Why call `rand` twice? It won't be the same, so assign it to a variable. Doh!

Comment: I don't see any proper `int x = 0` initialization so you could be starting from a garbage value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `rand` function when displaying the information and then again when saving which explains the disparity.

Answer (score 0):

Each call of `rand`will return a new value. So the value you print is **not** the same as the value you use for the sum.

The solution is to call `rand`only once and save the result in a temporare variable. Something like:

```
int tmp;
int x = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    tmp = rand();  // Only call rand once !

    printf(" %d time dice rolled = %d \n",i, tmp % s + 1);
    x += tmp % s + 1;
}
printf("--------------------------------------Sum is %d", x);
```